# Raspberry Pi with 4 cameras and Multi Camera Adapter Module

Tags: camera

I am trying to do my first project on RPi.

**What is it:**
The device will have 4 cameras and all of it need to take atleast 3 images per second at an average speed of 20kmph when a button is pressed. That is I intend to put the finished project on something like my bike.

**What I have at the moment:**
Class 10 microsd card
Raspberry Pi Model B+

**What I need:**
I need to find cameras which can take decent images(not of great quality, but ok ones) while the whole set up is traveling at around 20KMPH. I don't know which camera should I select.

Comment: DIY Street View. I like it.

Comment: I am aware of the `cheese` application for web-cams but you'd need an instance for each of the (presumably USB) cameras.  I think your biggest issues will be: A) powering all the cameras - you probably will need a powered hub - and then you will need to have something to power everything whilst mobile (12V gel Lead-Acid battery, wired to a Cigarette-lighter socket with a High power {most likely 10+ W} multi-USB Cigarette-lighter adapter - one output to power RPi and one for the Hub); B) having a high enough data rate to get output from all cameras through the USB system and through the RPi...!

Comment: So how come some of these cheap drones are able to capture HD videos and take images while flying? Can't I use that technology in my project?

Comment: @defiant The cameras in those drones use dedicated hardware. On the Pi, you're processing the images on-the-fly.

Comment: @defiant Oh, and your quality will also depend on the camera. I got webcams that work extremely quickly in bright surroundings (sunlit). Even phone cameras work that way. These usually blur out when taking quick photos in not-so-bright scenes.

Comment: @PandaLion98 Can you suggest cameras like that available in the market which are not too bulky?

Answer (score 3):

Browsing around, I found this: http://www.arducam.com/multi-camera-adapter-module-raspberry-pi/

Since the interface bandwidth isn't that great, a workaround (or solution?) would be to quickly switch between the cameras. The site provides some Python code to do just that.

Comment: I am in contact with them. The problem is, they are saying, the images will turn out blurry if I am traveling at 20KMPH. Also taking images from all the cameras at 3images per second can't be done because of delays caused by the clock cycles!